# Recover files in Ubuntu from USB stick

Tags: 11.04, installation, boot, kernel

I have Ubuntu 11.04 running from a USB stick. I think I ran some updates in terminal and now it has a kernel panic during boot up. Is there a way I can get hold of files I saved when Ubuntu was working?

I just managed to watch the booot screen and it looks as if there are some errors saying there is no room to write to disk however my USB stick has 5GB free

**UPDATE:** Here is what I see when I plug the USB stick into Windows
[image: My filesystem]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work by resizing the casper-rw file using [this tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-resize-casper-rw-images/).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have used the Universal USB Installer from [pendrivelinux.com](http://pendrivelinux.com) you need to use a tool that allows you to resize the casper-rw file in your USB's root.

[Download](http://www.henrynestler.com/colinux/tools/toporesize-0.7.1.zip) TopoResize and unzip it's contents.

Open `toporesize.bat` from the TopoResize folder to start the program.

Once the application starts

1. Click find file and navigate to the casper-rw file you would like to
   resize
2. Drag the slider to the desired capacity, (3) Click Resize fileresize
   casper-rw using TopoResize

That's all there is to it.

If all goes well, you should now have a resized casper-rw partition and the *no space* errors will not show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you made your Live USB stick. Did you make it with a persistence file? That option is present when you make the USB with either the Ubuntu USB creator or UNetBootin. If you didn't make a persistence file then all the files or changes you make will be lost on reboot. If there is a persistence file, and your USB wont boot its possible to explore the USB on a different system and see if you can find your files in the home folder or other directory you downloaded them to.

Comment: I used Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux.com.  Files are getting saved somewhere as I have removed the pen drive and then re- inserted days later and my files were there.  I cannot find a LINUX looking file system when I put the USB into a Windows machine

Comment: There is no native support for ext2/3/4 filesystem in Windows. Get following and you should be able to read the stick in Windows: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

Answer (score 0):

You can mount casper-rw and access files within using:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper

sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```